R message: all the Accuracy metric values are missing when trying to make an ada model
I have a dataset about credit risk and have preprocessed my data, now I am trying to train and test on an ada boost model but it gives me the following error message: Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing.
Help please I am very beginner in r and do not know how to fix.
This is my code block, starting from tree_ada it does not run, can someone help me fix it or understand how it should be done please?
tree_ada=train(Risk~.,data=train,method="ada")
tree_ada
tree_ada_tune=train(Risk~.,data=train,method="ada",
                    tuneGrid=expand.grid(nu=0.1,maxdepth=c(1:3),
                                         iter=c(50,75,100)))
tree_ada_tune

here is my pre processing in case it will help give context:
# download libraries
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
library(rattle) # plot trees


# import credit_data 

data=credit_data
summary(data)
str(data)

# Replace the missing values of Saving.accounts and Checking.account in credit_data to unknown
data$Saving.accounts[is.na(data$Saving.accounts)] = 'unknown'
data$Checking.account[is.na(data$Checking.account)] = 'unknown'
data

# Count how many unknowns we have
sum(data$Saving.accounts == "unknown")
# 183 for Saving.accounts out of the 1000 observations
sum(data$Checking.account == "unknown")
# 394 for Checking.account out of the 1000 observations

# Remove column X in the dataframe, no important information, don't need it
credit_data$X=NULL

# see the new dataframe, without this column
print(data)

# Calculating correlation matrix
correlation_matrix = cor(data[, sapply(data, is.numeric)])

# Display the correlation matrix
print(correlation_matrix)
# We can see a moderate/high correlation (0.62498420), between Duration and Credit Amount

# Convert the cat to factors
data$Sex <- as.factor(data$Sex)
data$Housing <- as.factor(data$Housing)
data$Job <- as.factor(data$Job)
data$Saving.accounts <- as.factor(data$Saving.accounts)
data$Checking.account <- as.factor(data$Checking.account)
data$Purpose <- as.factor(data$Purpose)
data$Risk <- as.factor(data$Risk)
str(data)

# Randomly select 70% of the data for training, and 30% will be used for prediction and testing 
# split data intro train vs test set
index = createDataPartition(data$Risk, p=0.7, list=F) # randomly select observation from our dataset, 1. need target variable, 2. proportion of train and test, not fixed, 3. if you want it presented like a list or not
train = data[index,] # row and column
test = data[-index,] # will take all observations except the index

tree_ada=train(Risk~.,data=train,method="ada")
tree_ada
tree_ada_tune=train(Risk~.,data=train,method="ada",
                    tuneGrid=expand.grid(nu=0.1,maxdepth=c(1:3),
                                         iter=c(50,75,100)))
tree_ada_tune

what i tried is this and the r response is:Something is wrong; all the Accuracy metric values are missing:
Accuracy       Kappa
Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA
1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA
Median : NA   Median : NA
Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN
3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA
Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA
NA's   :9     NA's   :9

I had the same problem as you because R didn't accept the name of variables I used. More specifically I have used one hot encoding, and categorizing variables in "1" e "0".
Instead, I tried to use XO and X1 and it solved it.
Check thoroughly in SO website because there are many similar questions.
